# How to Make Apollo Client iOS Accept Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: apollo-ios

How does one make ApolloClient accept self-signed certificates? We are using it for internal apps, and calls to the GraphQL endpoints are failing because of the certification issues. I found [this thread](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/61) in the repository issues, but it seems that the API has changed some since that discussion, and the correct current approach is eluding me.

Currently, my integration test drops to the `.failure` branch reporting certificate validation issues:

```swift
        let apollo = AppConstants.current.apollo
        apollo.fetch( query: DriverStatementsIncompleteQuery( onepass: "test-user" ) ) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success( let results ):
                print( results )
                XCTAssertNil( results.errors )
                self.completedExpectation.fulfill()
            case .failure( let error ):
                XCTFail( error.localizedDescription )
                self.completedExpectation.fulfill()
            }
        }
        wait( for: [self.completedExpectation], timeout: 5 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ellen Shapiro on the Apollo iOS team very kindly pointed me in the right direction. Here's what I ended up with:

```swift
public struct PromiscuousApolloClientFactory {
    /// Creates an `ApolloClient` instance that is configured to work with certificates that the
    /// OS would otherwise deem invalid, like those that are self-signed.
    /// - Parameter endpointURL: The URL of the GraphQL endpoint.
    /// - Returns: The configured `ApolloClient` instance.
    public static func make( with endpointURL: URL ) -> ApolloClient {
        let store = ApolloStore( cache: InMemoryNormalizedCache() )
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let client = PromiscuousURLSessionClient( sessionConfiguration: sessionConfig )
        let provider = LegacyInterceptorProvider( client: client, store: store )
        let transport = RequestChainNetworkTransport( interceptorProvider: provider, endpointURL: endpointURL )
        
        return ApolloClient( networkTransport: transport, store: store )
    }
}

private class PromiscuousURLSessionClient: URLSessionClient {
    override func urlSession( _ session: URLSession,
                              didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                              completionHandler: @escaping ( URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential? ) -> Void ) {
        let protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace
        
        guard protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
              let serverTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
                completionHandler( .performDefaultHandling, nil )
                return
        }
        
        let credential = URLCredential( trust: serverTrust )
        completionHandler( .useCredential, credential )
    }
}
```

**NOTE BENE**: This is generally a bad practice, as it short-circuits security protections that are there for your own good. If you have a path to use certificates that the OS can validate, do that instead. :)